# Make Buttons/Labels on windows form bigger/move position on maximise?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, forms

I am developing a clock Timer.  It is working fine however I am having a issue when the form which is normally small to sit in the corner of the screen out of the way is maximised.  Is there a way when it is maximised that I can move the location of the Activity (where all the info is enetered) - I can move that start pause and stop/reset button and I can also move the labels which countdown the time and make them a lot bigger on the maximised display.  I have two images - background small and background large which are changing fine on the maximise - I used the code below too hook into the size change event - however the commented out is not working - it does not let be hard code the X,Y co-ordinates of where i would like the activity on maximise...is there something I am missing?

Many Thanks - Colly.

```
    private void CountDownTimer_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image Max = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\colinmck\Desktop\Timer\CountDownTimer\IgnitionTeamLRG.bmp");
        Image Min = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\colinmck\Desktop\Timer\CountDownTimer\IgnitionTeamSML.bmp");
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {

            BackgroundImage = Max;
            //Not Working!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //Activity.Location.X = 60;
            //Activity.Location.Y = 65;


        }
        else
        {
            BackgroundImage = Min;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location.X and Location.Y are read only properties. You should try...

```
Activity.Location = new Point(60, 65);
```

Perhaps also take a look into the Anchor property for auto resizing of controls: http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/C-Resizing-controls-with-form-Anchor-property/52689

Comment: Hi @musefan.  I am able to resize a label which i use to display the coutdown details - however the text inside the label does not re-size - would you have any ideas how to do this?